generalized progressive hybrid censoring scheme type 1 and Muth distribution
I have data concerning failure of sodium sulfur battery cells with the following numeric values:  76,82,210,315,385,412,491,504,522,646+,678,775,884,1131,1446,1824,1827,2248,2385,3077.
This  dataset is provided in this paper , see here link [https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1687850723001024][1]
It represents the failure of 20 cells with one being right censored (646+).
The proposed analysis follows GPHCS type I with: r=7 out m=10 and n=20(total sample size)
3 schemes are proposed for the analysis as illustrated in the paper.
The first one is: 7 failed items with the following times(0.076, .315,.385,.415,.522,.678,.775), prefixed time determined to end the study at .5 and the removal items are as follows : 9 items are removed at first failure, then zero items are removed at each subsequent failure time, this is denoted as (9, 0^9).
the second scheme is : 8 failed items with the following times( 0.076, .082,.21,.315,.385,.775,.884, 1.131), prefixed time determined to end the study at 1.3,  and the removal items are as follows: zero items are removed at first, second, third and fourth failure, then 5 items are removed at fifth failure, 4 items at 6th failure and zero at each subsequent failure time, i.e (0^4,5,4,0^4).
the third scheme is: 10 failed items with times (.076,.082,.21,.315,.385,.412,.491,.504,.522,.678) and prefixed time to end the study at .9 and removal scheduled at (0^9, 9).
the paper proposed that the data follows the muth distribution. To obtain the Mle for the parameter using loglikelihhod as shown in equation 8 in the paper. It is difficult to solve analytically and using MCMC is an alternative approach. This can be done for both Bayesian and non-Bayesian approaches.
My question is how to do this using R.
How to represent the data with different schemes in R?
what are the packages needed for this?
And can you provide me with an example of the code?
